# Is it time to remove the Main Site's feed from The Oracle in chat?

Tags: discussion

There is a sufficient volume of questions such that the Oracle seems to be the main poster in chat on quiet days.

I assert that this volume of posting is meaningless, especially with the newish AJAX that provides for auto-updating of the main page, and that it provides nor stimulates no conversation.

Any objections to me removing it?

(I'm going to leave the meta-feed regardless, cause that does require attention-getting)

Comment: If we decided it's time to go, please just switch it to a drop down feed.

Comment: Please proceed, this is plenty of consensus.

Answer (score 10):

I think we should swap it to the dropdown feed type. At this point with the larger question volume sometimes does interfere with actual chat going on in the room.

The other thing is that if we eliminate the actual posting in the room, it means that questions/answers that are oneboxed in the room are clearly relevant to the current discussion instead of potentially random.

Answer (score 0):

So that instead, there will be no volume there at all?  Not sure what the value of removal is.

Comment: it just interrupts conversations :)