# How are ticker feeds for chat selected?

Tags: discussion, chat, feed

[Here is a list of the feeds that currently show up in RPG General Chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11/rpg-general-chat?tab=feeds)

How are these feeds selected?

What's the community's procedure for suggestions additions or modifications to the feeds?

Comment: Honestly we just picked some early on.  You can just ask if you want something added.

Comment: @C.Ross I kinda figured. But it feels like some community-wide criteria and process -- even if it's a dirt simple one -- might be nice.

Comment: Feel free to propose one?  I think the only non-negotiable is site and meta questions in the main room.

Comment: Yeah, we just added a couple to get started when we got the functionality, with the assumption that once anyone cares they'll start proposing more things. We try to not put processes in place proactively, it's wasteful. One emerges when there's enough demand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been suggested in the comments that I propose a process.

Here is a process. It is intentionally kinda informal.

- We make a meta thread for it like the [community ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013).
- People vote stuff up or down depending on whether they would like to see it in the chat feed.
- Moderators use these ratings as a guide to adjust the feeds.

Comment: +5/-0 at the moment... Anyone object to me going ahead and putting up a meta thread like this? (It won't actually *do* anything until mods decide to apply the data.)

Comment: go for it. +5 is nearly a quorum of regular chat users

Answer (score 3):

In the general sense, they are controlled by the moderators or room owners. Any stack exchange moderator is a chat moderator so there are a lot of people with the ability to change the feeds.

The main RPG room feeds are as follows:

- A ticker feed of questions asked on the site
- A post feed of meta questions asked
- A ticker feed for gnome stew
- A ticker feed for aggregated RPG blogs
- A ticker feed for the Enworld news page

Generally it's up to the consensus of whoever is in chat when someone feels like changing the feeds. Although there is occasionally a meta process related to it. Things like the big decision to switch the mainsite question feed to a ticker was made here on [meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/is-it-time-to-remove-the-main-sites-feed-from-the-oracle-in-chat).

However, as these kinds of things are fluid it's not completely necessary for it to go through meta to change.

All that to say, if you want something added or removed, just ask.

Comment: the "ENWorld thread" is the ENWorld News page.

Comment: @mxyzplk thanks, updated.

Comment: Might be time to remove Gnome Stew, they're about dead.